# Multiplying two variables in XSLT-1

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have tried for hours to multiply 2 varibales in XSLT1 but I can't seem to figure it out.
The result shows in excel as NaN
I have searched for a while but I'm having trouble with this, just started using XSLT

Variables:

- Weight = 10
- Length = 12

XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name ="content"><xsl:value-of select="$length * $weight" /></xsl:variable>
```

**EDIT:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:rvmon="rosenbergverft.com:3D/2017/WeightMTO" xmlns:pdms="rosenbergverft.com:3D/2010/Models">
  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" standalone="no" media-type="text/xls" />
  <xsl:decimal-format name="euro" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="." />

  <xsl:template match="/">Building block;Discipline;Area;Sub. Area;Syst. no.;Weight Item no.;Piecemark no.;Weight Item Descr.;CompType;Type code;Rating or Scedule;Spec.;Dim. (");Material;Cost Code COR;Weight Phase Code;Mod. Phase Code;Weight Status % (allow.);Mod. Constr. Code;Mod. Handl. Code;No. off;Unit Length/ Area (m,m2, m3);Unit Weight (kg/m, m2, m3);Unit Weight MON(kg/m, m2, m3);Net Dry Weight (kg);Gross Dry Weight (kg);Content Weight (kg);Installed weight;CoG East;CoG North;CoG Elevation;Ref. doc., dwg., P&amp;ID etc.;Remarks;Cost for instrument valves [NOK];install code;MON Lift Code;Paint Surface;Insulation Class;
<xsl:for-each select="/rvmon:WeightMTO/rvmon:MTOOwner"><xsl:for-each select="rvmon:Piecemark/rvmon:WeightItemNo/rvmon:Part">


<xsl:variable name= "weight" select="format-number(rvmon:ContentWeight/@number, '#0,0##', 'euro')"  />
<xsl:variable name="length"><xsl:choose><xsl:when test="contains(rvmon:CompType,'BOLT')"><xsl:text> 1 </xsl:text></xsl:when><xsl:when test="rvmon:UnitLength/@unit = 'mm'"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(rvmon:UnitLength/@number div 1000, '#0,0##', 'euro')" /></xsl:when><xsl:when test="rvmon:UnitLength/@unit = 'mm2'"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(rvmon:UnitLength/@number div 1000000, '#0,0##', 'euro')" /></xsl:when><xsl:when test="rvmon:UnitLength/@unit = 'mm3'"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(rvmon:UnitLength/@number div 1000000000, '#0,0##', 'euro')" /></xsl:when><xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="format-number(rvmon:UnitLength/@number, '#0,0##', 'euro')" /></xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="content" select="$length * $weight" />


<xsl:value-of select="../../../rvmon:BuildingBlock" />;<xsl:value-of select="rvmon:Discipline" />;<xsl:value-of select="../../../rvmon:Module" />;<xsl:value-of select="../../../rvmon:SubArea" />;<xsl:value-of select="../../../rvmon:SystNo" />;<xsl:value-of select="rvmon:WeightItemNo" />;<xsl:value-of select="rvmon:Piecemark" />;<xsl:value-of select="rvmon:WeightItemDescr" />;<xsl:value-of select="rvmon:CompType" />;<xsl:value-of select="rvmon:TypeCode" />;<xsl:value-of select="rvmon:Rating" />;<xsl:value-of select="rvmon:Spec" />;<xsl:choose><xsl:when test="rvmon:Discipline = 'L'"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(rvmon:Dim/@number, '#0,##', 'euro')" /><xsl:choose><xsl:when test="rvmon:Dim/@unit = 'inch'">"</xsl:when><xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="rvmon:Dim/@unit" /></xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose></xsl:when><xsl:when test="rvmon:Discipline = 'N'"></xsl:when><xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="format-number(rvmon:Dim/@number, '#0,##', 'euro')" /><xsl:value-of select="rvmon:Dim/@unit" /></xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose>;<xsl:value-of select="rvmon:Material" />;<xsl:value-of select="rvmon:CostCodeCOR" />;<xsl:value-of select="rvmon:WeightPhaseCode" />;<xsl:value-of select="rvmon:ModPhaseCode" />;<xsl:value-of select="format-number(rvmon:WeightStatus/@number * 100, '00', 'euro')" />%;<xsl:value-of select="rvmon:ModConstrCode" />;<xsl:value-of select="rvmon:ModHandlCode" />;<xsl:value-of select="format-number(rvmon:NoOff/@number, '#0,###', 'euro')" />;<xsl:value-of select="$length"/>;<xsl:if test="rvmon:ModHandlCode = 'RP'">-</xsl:if><xsl:value-of select="format-number(rvmon:UnitWeight/@number, '#0,0##', 'euro')" />;<xsl:if test="rvmon:ModHandlCode = 'RP'">-</xsl:if><xsl:value-of select="format-number(rvmon:MONUnitWeightFactor/@number, '#0,0#####', 'euro')" />;<xsl:choose><xsl:when test="contains(rvmon:CompType,'BOLT')"><xsl:text> 1 </xsl:text></xsl:when><xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="format-number(rvmon:NetDryWeight/@number, '#0,0##', 'euro')" /></xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose>;<xsl:value-of select="format-number(rvmon:AllowanceWeight/@number, '#0,0##', 'euro')" />;<xsl:if test="rvmon:ModHandlCode = 'RP'">-</xsl:if><xsl:value-of select="$weight"/>;<xsl:if test="rvmon:ProdStatus ='ABC' "><xsl:text> Yes </xsl:text></xsl:if>;<xsl:value-of select="format-number(rvmon:CoGEast/@number div 1000, '#0,0##', 'euro')" />;<xsl:value-of select="format-number(rvmon:CoGNorth/@number div 1000, '#0,0##', 'euro')" />;<xsl:value-of select="format-number(rvmon:CoGElevation/@number div 1000, '#0,0##', 'euro')" />;<xsl:value-of select="../../../rvmon:DrawNumber" />;<!-- xsl:value-of select="rvmon:Remarks" / --><xsl:value-of select="../../../pdms:PDMSElement/pdms:ElementName/@text" />;;;;<xsl:value-of select="format-number(rvmon:PaintSurface/@number div 1000000, '#0,0##', 'euro')" />;<xsl:value-of select="../../../rvmon:InsulationClass" />;<xsl:value-of select="$length"/>;<xsl:value-of select="$content"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text></xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML-document

```html
          <UnitLength number="1.000" unit="pcs" field="Quantity" />
          <ContentWeight number="8.005" unit="kg" field="ContentWeight" /> />
```

I am able to output "weight" and "length" by itself. But I cant even do 
"weight * 10"

Sorry if it is messy.

Comment: have you tried casting it to `number()` ? `number($length) * number($weight)`

Comment: For context, please also show the `<xsl:variable>` elements that define those variables, and cross-check that they contain what you think they do by outputting them using `<xsl:value-of>` and show the exact error you get.

Comment: In other words, make an [mcve]. A single line of XSLT with no context at all is not enough to determine what is going on.

Comment: Basically, the code you've shown us is correct. The bug is therefore in the code that you haven't shown us.

Comment: Though even in the code you've shown us, there's a gross (but sadly very common) inefficiency. Rather than using `xsl:value-of`, you should write `<xsl:variable name="content" select="$length * $weight" />`. That affects performance and readability, but it doesn't account for the incorrect results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove all formatting number while assigning the variable and while multipled result need to format number like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:rvmon="rosenbergverft.com:3D/2017/WeightMTO" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:decimal-format name="euro" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="." />

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name= "weight" select="//rvmon:ContentWeight/@number"  />
        <xsl:variable name="length">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(//rvmon:CompType,'BOLT')">
                    <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="rvmon:UnitLength/@unit = 'mm'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="//rvmon:UnitLength/@number div 1000" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="rvmon:UnitLength/@unit = 'mm2'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="//rvmon:UnitLength/@number div 1000000" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="rvmon:UnitLength/@unit = 'mm3'">
                   <xsl:value-of select="//rvmon:UnitLength/@number div 1000000000" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                   <xsl:value-of select="//rvmon:UnitLength/@number" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="content" select="format-number(($weight * $length), '#0,0##', 'euro')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$content"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: See result here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWEamKZ/1

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
<xsl:variable name= "weight" select="format-number(rvmon:ContentWeight/@number, '#0,0##', 'euro')"  />
```

A number formatted to use a decimal comma is no longer a number for the purposes of XPath/XSLT. A [number](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#NT-Number) can contain only digits and a decimal period.

Assuming that the original values (not shown in your question) are true numbers, use them for the multiplication, and format them only for the output.